# How to read sql XML field in .Net

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, xmldocument

In .Net, dataset contains field with following xml data in it. I ran the script in sql to generate xml data which now i need to read in .net (c# or vb.net)

```
  <Candidate>
    <Inspector InspectorID="6390" name="John Doe">
      <Qualification>
        <Qualification docid="23107" filesize="248724" name="AWS CWI" enddate="2016-12-01T00:00:00" datecreated="2014-07-23T21:30:00" />
      </Qualification>
    </Inspector>
    <Inspector InspectorID="6564" name="Jane Roe">
      <Qualification>
        <Qualification docid="25183" filesize="48114" name="CSWIP 3.1 Welding (or equiv)" enddate="2015-11-01T00:00:00" datecreated="2014-08-27T12:47:00" />
        <Qualification docid="25185" filesize="449518" name="RT Level II" enddate="2017-12-17T00:00:00" datecreated="2014-08-27T12:52:00" />
        <Qualification docid="25186" filesize="156923" name="UT Level II" enddate="2018-01-28T00:00:00" datecreated="2014-08-27T12:54:00" />
      </Qualification>
    </Inspector>
  </Candidate>
```

I am trying to read data for certain inspector but it is not working.

```
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    Dim nodes As XmlNodeList
    doc.LoadXml(TextBox1.Text)
    nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/Candidate/Inspector/Qualification/Qualification[@InspectorID=" & 6390 & "]")
    Dim node As XmlNode
    For Each node In nodes
        MsgBox(node.SelectSingleNode("docid").InnerText)
        MsgBox(node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText)
        MsgBox(node.SelectSingleNode("filesize").InnerText)
    Next
```

Comment: Are you getting some error, please share details

Comment: Your `SelectNodes()` expression needs to be fixed, you want to have the predicate on `Inspector` element, e.g. `"/Candidate/Inspector[@InspectorID=" & 6390 & "]/Qualification/Qualification"`. Also later you are trying to select a child element, e.g. in `MsgBox(node.SelectSingleNode("docid").InnerText)`, while you want an attribute, so you may want to try changing the expression to `MsgBox(node.SelectSingleNode("@docid").InnerText)`, or alternatively you could define `node` as `XmlElement` and use `GetAttribute()`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Pavel; many thanks for your response. I have changed the code with your correction and it is working :) . One question here, is there anyway to loop through all inspectors without giving their ID's?

Comment: @user1263981 simply remove the predicate : `/Candidate/Inspector/Qualification/Qualification`